# Web resources or other resources for villa rentals in Europe? (Spain, France, Italy etc.)

Tags: europe, online-resources, accommodation, hotels, rental

Im looking for resources ala [hotels.com](http://hotels.com) but only for villa rentals. Does anyone know of any good sites like this?

Comment: I've changed this to a community wiki.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few just by Googling.

[Amalfi Coast 1](http://www.luxuryretreats.com/ppc/landings/amalfi-coast/index.aspx?utm_source=Google_&utm_medium=CPC&utm_term=NA&utm_content=VILLARENTAL&utm_campaign=ITALYAMALFI&gclid=CJLYyp-Qpa0CFYFx4AodPS8dsg), Amalfi Coast 2

Here is all Europe: http://www.rentvillas.com/

Answer (score 5):

In Belgium try http://www.belsud.be

Answer (score 5):

For France, a great site for renting farmhouses in coutryside or small villages is [Gîtes de France](http://en.gites-de-france.com/).

Answer (score 4):

I'd take a look at [Air Bnb](http://www.airbnb.com/), it's starting to really appeal to me for big bookings, or for non-standard hotel bookings.

Answer (score 3):

Just an addition to Mark Mayo's answer, [Roomorama](https://roomorama.com/) is also a website that similar to [AirBnb](http://www.airbnb.com/).

Answer (score 2):

In Spain the biggest (and also the one that offers better prices) is [idealista](http://www.idealista.com/pagina/portada?opidiom=cidioma&localeRef=en). You can try to find by "rent" "holiday" in any of the country areas. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The largest such site is http://homeaway.com, which is a big roll-up of many smaller sites that got bought by the same company.

Comment: very usefull indeed!

Answer (score 2):

A great search site is [Otalo](http://www.otalo.com), it searches all the leading vacation rental sites (like airbnb, HomeAway, Niumba, etc.) for you.  They list over 500,000 [holiday rentals for just Europe](http://www.otalo.com/vacation-rentals/Europe/r.jsp):

Answer (score 1):

Another good website I found was this: http://www.provacances.com/